# Visual Studio: Unable to Locate Labels and others Elements in Form Designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently facing a problem in Visual Studio where I am unable to locate certain textboxes and labels in the form designer. Despite trying to drag new elements onto the form and renaming them to match the previous ones, I receive an error indicating that elements with the same names already exist. However, I cannot find these elements on the form designer.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Your insights are greatly appreciated. Thank you[image]

I attempted to locate missing textboxes and labels on the Visual Studio form designer. In an effort to troubleshoot, I tried dragging new elements onto the form and renaming them to match the missing ones.

Comment: Open the "Document Outline" for that form and look if you see control that you don'T expect(in the menu somewhere in  view/other views or as shortcut typically CTRL+W,U). If that does not help look for the MYLOVELYFORM.designer.cs file. That should contain the designer generated code and you may spot a problem in there.

Comment: Thanks! But, I have checkout these procedures but to no avail!

Comment: You can also look at the alphabetical list of controls in the properties panel. But chances are the designer file is out of sync. Back it all up and try to clean/regenerate!

Answer (score 0):

You can see what is on the form in Source view (like ASPX tags).  You can also open it in a split view to see the Design and Source at the same time.  You should be able to see everything that is on the form.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if Ralf's suggestion does not work for you, it is speculated that it is a problem with the Form. Go back to the Form.Designer.cs source file and still find the `InitializeComponent()` method, but this time you are not looking for control-related initialization. Manipulate the code, but find the code related to your Form.

Every time a new control is added, the corresponding initialization code will be generated in `InitializeComponent()`. The added control name annotation is used as the beginning and is generated sequentially, so you can use ctrl+F to search for the control name (form's name).

Of course, the code in InitializeComponent() includes control initialization and window initialization code. Generally, window initialization will be in the last code block, so slide to the end of the InitializeComponent() method to find the window (Form) related initialization code fragment.

As shown in the figure below, this window is named Form1. Check whether the this.Controls.Add() related method is missing. This method is used to add controls to the specified control collection. In other words, under normal circumstances, if several controls are added to the form, there will be several add methods to complete the missing ones.

[image]

Also, did you use a container control like tabcontrol?